# How can I enclose a link in brackets in org-mode for html export?

Tags: org-export, hyperlinks

I want to create links in my html output that are enclosed in brackets, so look like this: [PDF].  I used to be able to do this by enclosing the whole link in the org file in another pair of brackets, like this: `[[[link][description]]]`.

This does not work any more: it used to work for me, but now I get an error: `Unable to resolve link: "[some.site"`.  I tried different ways of doing this (e.g. escaping the brackets), but nothing seems to work.  Is this possible?

EDIT: in response to questions, here's what the html output should look like:

```
[<a href="https://some.site">description</a>]
```

Comment: Could you show us what the generated HTML you want should look like?

Comment: SInce it's the description that shows, I imagine you mean brackets around the description - correct?

Comment: Yes, enclosed by brackets.  See EDIT.

Comment: Surrounding the whole link with brackets works for me. Do you get an error? What does "it does not work any more" mean exactly?

Comment: It used to work for me.  But now I get an error: Unable to resolve link: "[https://some.site"

Comment: Cut-and-paste the contents of the file to your question and we can try it out. Also post the version of Org-mode you are using: `M-x org-version`.

Comment: Org mode version 9.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my understanding is correct: the square brackets are *not* semantic markup (they don't trigger/mean anything), they are purely to draw attention; in other words, they are styling. This sounds to me like something that should be done using CSS. Doing it in CSS will offer many advantages: it is automatic, it is 100% reliable and consistent, and perhaps most importantly, it does not clutter your content with semantically extraneous bracket characters.

For advice on CSS, you should visit for instance https://webapps.stackexchange.com/